# Nextjs server side permanent redirection rather 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-rewrites

I have a Next.js app with three routes: **/home**, **/about**, and **/contact**.

If a user lands on a route that doesn't exist, by default, Next.js will direct them to the 404 page.

However, I want to avoid redirecting them to the 404 page. Instead, I'd like to establish a permanent redirection to **/home**. This means that if someone lands on an unavailable route, they will automatically be redirected to **/home**.

I need to set this up from the server side in the Next.js config file. The reason for this is that I recently acquired a domain, and users are currently hitting a lot of 404 pages for URLs that used to be live. I want to minimize the number of users encountering 404 errors.

While it's relatively straightforward to implement this when we know the specific unknown page a user might land on, without knowing the exact routes, we'll likely need to use a regex pattern. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

Could you please provide guidance on potential solutions or approaches to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could export a custom 404 page and redirect users to your home page.

```
export default function Custom404() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => router.push('/home'), [router])
  return <h1>Oops! We didn't find this page. We'll redirect you to home page</h1>
}
```

Users will still show a 404 page but I don't think it's a good idea to avoid this. Users have to know that the requested url doesn't exist.
You'd better understand why so many users lands on this page.

Comment: Yes, we can do it. However, the main issue is that I want to respond to unknown routes with a permanent redirection to /home. Adding useEffect in the 404 page will still result in a lot of 404 requests.

Comment: You cannot do that, except by defining ALL unexisting routes in the redirect function of next.config.js. Otherwise, user request will always try to reach a resource on the server that doesn't exist, and you cannot avoid that. 404 page does exist for a reason. But I don't think next.config.js provides a catch all route.

Comment: You can perform redirection on server side tho, but tout users will still reach 404.